# compare List of attributes against an object inside list

Tags: python

This is how my Input looks like:

```
cust1Attributes = [{'Key': 'FirstName', 'Value': 'SomeFirstName'}, {'Key': 'LastName', 'Value': 'SomeLastName'}]
```

This is how my MandatoryData list looks like:

```
class MustHaveData(object):
    def __init__(self, name, defaultValue):
        self.name = name
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue

customerMandatoryData=[]
customerMandatoryData.append(MustHaveData(name="FirstName", defaultValue="Default First Name"))
customerMandatoryData.append(MustHaveData(name="LastName", defaultValue="Default Last Name"))
customerMandatoryData.append(MustHaveData(name="State", defaultValue="Default State"))
```

I need to compare `cust1Attributes's key` against `customerMandatoryData's name` and get the list of `customerMandatoryData` back which does not exist for `cust1Attributes`

How do i do this?

Comment: Why are you using a list of dictionaries taht each have one value?  You would find your data structure much easier to work with if it was just a normal dictionary: `{'FirstName': 'SomeFirstName', 'LastName': SomeLastName}`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: That is what i am getting from the source system and i have no control over how it generates the JSON objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a *set* from the dictionary containing the items at each `Key` and use a *list comprehension* to filter out objects with names in the set:

```
custset = {x['Key'] for x in cust1Attributes}
result = [obj for obj in customerMandatoryData if obj.name not in custset]
```